# Help solve a problem about the leisure demand/labor supply mode. Halfway solved but fear my solution can't be right?

Tags: labor-economics

I've attached the question along with my current (incomplete) solution, but am unsure if my solution to part b makes sense given the question in part c. No substitution effect if demand for leisure is perfectly inelastic? Any help would be appreciated, thanks so much. Let me know if I'm on the wrong track about any of this, and tips for parts d & e would also be helpful.
[image]

[image]

[image]